# Fixing the error: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure why this is not working:

```
if($strFilterByStatus != 'all' &&  $strFilterByYear == 'all' && $strFilterByMonth !='all')
{
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblcase where recovered = '".$strFilterByStatus."' and monthreported = '".$strFilterByMonth."'" ;
}
else if($strFilterByStatus != 'all' &&  $strFilterByYear != 'all' && $strFilterByMonth !='all')
{
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblcase where recovered = '".$strFilterByStatus."' and yearreported = '".$strFilterByYear."' and monthreported = '".$strFilterByMonth."'" ;
}


if (mysql_num_rows($strSQL)==0)
{
    $strCaseExist = false;
}
else
{
    $SQL=mysql_query($strSQL);  
    $strCaseExist = true;
}
```

I have 2 different SQL statements and I just want to know if it will return a record or not.

Comment: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Because you're not executing the query, simply setting a string containing the query

Comment: ah yeah mark baker your right dammmmmmn so stupid not to see that thank you

@ed cottrell thanks i will take it to consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not executing the query.check this [manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) for more details on `mysql_num_rows()` ,change your code like this

```
$resrce =mysql_query($strSQL)
if (mysql_num_rows($resrce)==0)
```

**Beware about mysql functions, they are insecure and deprecated. Choose mysqli or pdo**

Comment: yes correct thank you, been a while since i used php :)

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_num_rows` requires a resultset to be passed not a string variable. Change to the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query( $strSQL );
$strCaseExist = (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to execute the query BEFORE checking for num rows.